# Slide overlayment to side -100%

Tags: overlay

The script I'm looking for is a "full screen" overlayment (div) which directly onpageload slides to left:-100% and the lower div / page will be visible.

I've been searching and testing for a while now but I can't seem to find a good and easy script.

I think the script would look a bit like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#activator').click(function(){
            $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $('#box').animate({'left':'0'},500);
            });
        });
        $('#boxclose').click(function(){
            $('#box').animate({'left':'100%'},500,function(){
                $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Is there anyone who knows some panel or slide script I can use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood what you were asking correctly, here is my solution -

http://jsfiddle.net/davemcmillan/zJryc/

Basically, in the javascript you first setup variables for the width and height of your container. You then set the overlay to have the width and height of your container.

Then you create the toggle function which just looks to see if the #overlay div has a class of 'closed' or not. If it has the class of 'closed', the onclick of the button will open the overlay, and if it doesn't, it will close it.

If you want the panel to open onload, you can just un-comment where I said in the Fiddle link.

Comment: Thanks allot Dave! 

Is there a way to slow the animation down?
It slides too fast!

Comment: because when i use the onload it goes too fast, or there should 2 sec timer befor it slides away.

Comment: Hey Marc, sure no problem. You just need a setTimeout on the toggle function then. I have updated the Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/davemcmillan/zJryc/

Comment: No problem Marc! Would you mind upvoting and adding my answer as the correct answer? Cheers

Comment: if i could i would, i already tried, Vote Up requires 15 reputation?!

Comment: I'm still a rookie at stackoverflow, sorry.

I have one (final) question about this js script.
Because I dont use the troggle to show it again, it would be best to let the overlay to be hidden after it has slided to the side.

This because when i change the browsersize a small part could appear again.
So basicly when slide is done, add style display:hidden somehow?

(As you might have noticed, I don't know much programming)

Comment: Hey Marc, here we go - http://jsfiddle.net/davemcmillan/hE4DK/  . This will simply slide the overlay out after 2 seconds and then hide the overlay. So no toggling etc. Cheers

Comment: Thanx again Dave! You are my hero :)

Comment: Cool no probs Marc. I've been posting some snippets etc on my own site. Check it out if you get a chance - http://davemcmillan.net